# Laravel/Lumen: Handling the fetchresults of Model::With('Relation')

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have three related tables:
Table Coretable which is referenced by Table extensiontable_itc and extensiontable_sysops.

I now want to get all the records from coretable which are referenced by extensiontable_itc and extensiontable_sysops, and to do so, I run this code:

```
$join = coretable::with('extensiontable_itc','extensiontable_sysops')->get();
```

and this kind of works, I get the following result:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_1",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "id": 1,
    "coretable_id": 1,
    "description": "EXTENSION_iTC_1",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "ID": 1,
    "coretable_id": 1,
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_1"
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_2",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "id": 4,
    "coretable_id": 2,
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_2",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "ID": 2,
    "coretable_id": 2,
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_2"
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_3",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "id": 5,
    "coretable_id": 3,
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_3",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "ID": 3,
    "coretable_id": 3,
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_3"
  }
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_4",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "id": 6,
    "coretable_id": 4,
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_4",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "ID": 4,
    "coretable_id": 4,
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_4"
  }
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_5",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "id": 7,
    "coretable_id": 5,
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_5",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "ID": 5,
    "coretable_id": 5,
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_5"
  }
}]
```

As you can see, the records referencing the respective record on coretable are put into an array, which itself becomes an element of the overall array containing the data from coretable.

Now, I want to get ALL this data EXCEPT for:

The ids from coretable

The created_at/updated_at

the foreign keys/coretable_ids

I already worked with the collection method "pluck()", but it doesn't seem to fit the purpose of accessing this multi-level array with all these duplicates in the indexes.

Is there any convenient way to do this? Or do I have to do it manually, using loops?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same, @V-K you should put that in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

There are two ways to hide fields. The first one is to put needed fields to `$hidden` array inside model class, and all these fields will not be included in the model instance. The second one is to use `makehidden` function. This allows you to hide fields dynamically, depend on some conditions as an example.